# 'System.String[]' cannot be mapped to a primitive type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to store array in database column.

```
public string[] carList { get; set; }
```

But it gives me the error:

> The property 'carList' on the type 'SandStormAdmin.Models.PricePlan' has a property type of 'System.String[]' which cannot be mapped to a primitive type.

It only gives me this error on run time, i am using microsoft sql server to store data. carList data Type store in table is of nvarchar(50)

***My Model class***

```
 public partial class PricePlan
    {
        public int PricePlanID { get; set; }
        public int CarID { get; set; }
        public string PricePlanName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateRangeFrom { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateRangeTo { get; set; }
        public string DayRangeFrom { get; set; }
        public string DayRangeTo { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public string[] carList { get; set; }

        public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
    }
```

***Create.cshtml***

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.carList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("carList", ViewBag.carlistname as SelectList, "Please Select Fruit name", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @multiple = "true" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.carList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        </div>
```

***PricePlanController***

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            //var result = (from carID in db.Cars select carID).ToList();
            //var getcarlist = db.Cars.ToList();
            SelectList list = new SelectList(db.Cars, "CarID", "Make");
            ViewBag.carlistname = list;
            //ViewBag.CarID = new SelectList(db.Cars, "CarID", "Make");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: PricePlans/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PricePlanID,CarID,PricePlanName,DateRangeFrom,DateRangeTo,DayRangeFrom,DayRangeTo,Amount,carList")] PricePlan pricePlan)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.PricePlans.Add(pricePlan);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }

            ViewBag.CarID = new SelectList(db.Cars, "CarID", "Make", pricePlan.Car);
            return View(pricePlan);
        }
```

[Database table data types picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmzt4.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2U9U.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmzt4.png)

Comment: Where is the database code?

Comment: Are u trying to to save an array in a varchar

Comment: The question does not have enough information. Only single line of code does not explain the issue you are facing. Are you using any any orm to map the property to column? Which orm you are using? You also need to share the data types of the column in the table. Are you getting error at runtime or compile time? If you are getting error at runtime then you need to share the code which throws the error.

Comment: yes I'm trying to save array in varchar

Comment: I updated the above code. Please let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to store an array of strings, which potentially contains multiple values, in a database column, which can only contain a single value.

There are two ways to solve this. The easiest would be to serialise the array into a single value before storing it. The following snippet uses `string.Join` to create a semicolon-separated string of all the values in `carList`:

```cs
var serialisedCarList = string.Join(";", carList);
```

The other option, which I would say is more idiomatic for relational databases, is to introduce a new table for the car values, and give them a foreign key to link them to a `PricePlan` record. This creates a one-to-many relationship from `PricePlan` records to `Car` records, effectively allowing a `PricePlan` to "contain" multiple car values.